# How to return the key with the max sum in a nested dictionary?

Tags: python, python-3.x

The title is a little confusing, and so is the actual question, truth be told. Say I have a dictionary with keys that are strings, and the value of such keys is another dictionary who's keys in return are strings with int values.

Like this:
`results = {'T1':{'team1': 1, 'team2': 3, 'team3': 10}, 'T2': {'team1': 3, 'team2': 1, 'team3': 5}}`

I want my code to return the team with the most goals overall, and if there's a tie, it should be a list of the teams that have a tie. If it's not a tie, I'd like there to be a list of length 1 with the winning team as the only string in the list.

The route I'm trying to go is making separate variables for each team, and in those variables, adding up the goals from each tournament (T1, T2). Then, using the max function I will find the variable with the highest value, and return either a list of the associated winning team or associated tied teams.

```
import operator

results = {'T1':{'team1': 1, 'team2': 3, 'team3': 10}, 'T2': {'team1': 3, 'team2': 1, 'team3': 5}}

def winning_team(results: dict[str, dict[str, int]]) -> list[str]:
    team_totals = {}
    for tournament in results:
        for team in tournament:
            team_total = 0
                for goals in team:
                    team_total += goals
                    team_totals[team] = team_total
    winning_list = []
    winning_list.append(max(team_totals.iteritems(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))[0])

    return winning_list

# when there's no tie

results = {'T1':{'team1': 1, 'team2': 3, 'team3': 10}, 'T2': {'team1': 3, 'team2': 1, 'team3': 5}}

>>> winning_team(results)
['team3']


# when there's a tie

new_results = {'T1':{'team1': 10, 'team2': 3, 'team3': 10}, 'T2': {'team1': 5, 'team2': 1, 'team3': 5}}

>>> winning_team(new_results)
['team1', 'team3'] # doesn't need to be in any particular order!
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import collections                                                                                                                                                 

results = {
    'T1': {
        'team1': 1,
        'team2': 3,
        'team3': 10,
    },
    'T2':
        {
        'team1': 3,
        'team2': 1,
        'team3': 5,
    },
}

totals = collections.Counter()

for tournament_results in results.values():
    totals.update(tournament_results)
winning_score = max(totals.values())
winners = [team for team, score in totals.items()
            if score == winning_score]
```

Comment: Using `collections.Counter` for the totals would let you streamline it even more. You can do `totals.update(tournament_results)` instead of your inner loop. The `most_common` method is also interesting, though it doesn't actually help the questioner in this situation, since it doesn't handle ties the way they need.

Answer (score 0):

This answer also checks for the ties and return them as a list.

```
import collections

results = {'T1':{'team1': 1, 'team2': 3, 'team3': 10}, 'T2': {'team1': 3, 'team2': 1, 'team3': 5}}

def winning_team(results):
    team_dict = {}

    for tournament, teams in results.items():
        for team in teams:
            score = teams[team]

            if team in team_dict:
                team_dict[team] = team_dict[team] + score
            else:
                team_dict[team] = score

    scores = list(team_dict.values())

    if len(scores) > len(set(scores)): # check for tie
        score_to_compare = [score for score, count in collections.Counter(scores).items() if count > 1]

        winning_list = [team for team, score in team_dict.items() if score in score_to_compare]
    else:
        score_to_compare = max(scores)

        winning_list = [team for team, score in team_dict.items() if score == score_to_compare]

    return winning_list
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way (run the program two times with two different `results`) :

```
import operator

results = {'T1': {'team1': 10, 'team2': 3, 'team3': 10}, 'T2': {'team1': 3, 'team2': 1, 'team3': 3}, 'T3': {'team1': 15, 'team2': 9, 'team3': 15}, 'T4': {'team1': 6, 'team2': 3, 'team3': 6}, 'T5': {'team1': 2, 'team2': 4, 'team3': 2}}
# results = {'T1': {'team1': 1, 'team2': 3, 'team3': 10}, 'T2': {'team1': 3, 'team2': 1, 'team3': 5}, 'T3': {'team1': 15, 'team2': 9, 'team3': 4}, 'T4': {'team1': 6, 'team2': 3, 'team3': 16}, 'T5': {'team1': 9, 'team2': 4, 'team3': 2}}


def winner(result):
    winner = [[]]   # list for winner team_names and results like [['team1', 'team2'], 100]
    teams_final_goals = {}  # dictionary for sum of all tournaments_goals for each team

    for _ in next(iter(result.values())):
        teams_final_goals[_] = 0    # initializing each team's score to 0

    for tournament in result:
        for team in result[tournament]:
            teams_final_goals[team] += result[tournament][team]     # adding goals scored by a team to teams_final_goals

    sorted_teams_final_goals = sorted(teams_final_goals.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True)  # sorting teams_final_goals in descending order

    # checking if it's a tie or not. if tie then both of the winning teams should be added in winners[team_name]
    if sorted_teams_final_goals[0][1] == sorted_teams_final_goals[1][1]:
        winner[0].append(sorted_teams_final_goals[0][0])
        winner[0].append(sorted_teams_final_goals[1][0])
        winner.append(sorted_teams_final_goals[0][1])
    else:
        winner[0].append(sorted_teams_final_goals[0][0])
        winner.append(sorted_teams_final_goals[0][1])

    return winner


final_result = winner(results)

# if winners[team_name] contains more than one value than it's a tie
if len(final_result[0]) > 1:
    print(f'It\'s a TIE! Winners are {final_result[0][0]}, {final_result[0][1]} and they scored {final_result[1]}')
else:
    print(f'Winner is {final_result[0][0]} and they scored {final_result[1]}')
```

Comment: Is there a way to sort without importing the operator module?

Comment: @Katerina Yes! `operator` is only used for sorting `teams_final_goals` dictionary according to goals_scored. If you don't want to use `operator` you just have to write some more code to sort the dictionary. BTW if you find the answer helpful and correct than you can give an up-vote and make it the accepted answer so that finding answer would be easier for others.